# How can I read information set with setpci?

Tags: hardware, eeepc, pci

I'm using setpci to set the clockspeed of my Intel 945GME like so:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 f0.b=00,60
setpci -s 00:02.0 f0.b=33,05
```

However I'm stuck on how to read the information back, I tried:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 f0.b
```

as the setpci man page says to simply omit the value to read the register, but it returns '03' regardless of what I've set. How can I read the value of the register so that a small script might check the current value?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a thorough rtfm-ing of man setpci:

> ...you should append a width specifier .B, .W, or .L to choose how many bytes (1, 2, or 4) should be transferred.